# Sort Array Of Files By Last Modified

Tags: php

Using the below action I gather a list of files and display them. I need to be able to sort the files by last modified date. Is there a simple way in PHP or using ZEND to order the items by last modified? If you know of a easier way to get the files and order them using ZEND; please let me know.

```
public function imagesAction()
{
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();

    $results = array();

    $handler = opendir(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/images/blog');

    while ($file = readdir($handler)) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file != '.svn') {
            $results[] = $file;
        }
    }

    closedir($handler);

    $this->view->data = $results;
}
```

I have tried doing

```
$this->view->data = ksort($results);
$this->view->data = asort($results);
```

But those just remove the entire list of files from the view and they stop showing up.

Comment: Does your result array contain data before you do ksort and asort? What about trying to sort before you do $this -> view -> data i.e Use $sort = ksort($results); and then $this->view->data = $sort;

Comment: @WebChemist I am trying to find a way to translate the above code into using ZEND if possible.

Comment: @socialrel8 - Yes; the code currently functions as is. I am able to get a result and populate my fields with the data but I need it to be sorted by last modified. I will try to create a intermediary variable and send that to the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function imagesAction()
{
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();

    $results = array();

    $handler = opendir(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/images/blog');

    while ($file = readdir($handler)) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file != '.svn') {
            $results[] = array('file' => $file, 'time' => filemtime($file));
        }
    }

    closedir($handler);

    uasort($results, function($file1, $file2) {
        if ( $file1['time'] == $file2['time'] )
           return 0;
        return $file1['time'] < $file2['time'] ? -1 : 1;
    });

    $this->view->data = $results;
}
```

Comment: Now I am getting the below; shouldn't it include a time?
Array
(
    [16] => Array
        (
            [file] => SS-2012.04.30-18.48.54_art3.png
            [time] => 
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [file] => Headliner Valve.jpg
            [time] => 
        )
}

Comment: I think you must provide the absolute path to file.

Comment: You are correct. I added the absolute path and changed the way my view handled the return. It works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: PHP7.3+ `uasort($results,function($file1,$file2){
   return $file1['time']<=>$file2['time'];
});`

Answer (score 0):

Use the last modified date as the key:

```
while ($file = readdir($handler)) {
    if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file != '.svn') {
        $s = stat($file);
        if (!is_array($results[$s['mtime']]) {
             $results[$s['mtime']] = array();
        }
        $results[$s['mtime']][] = $file;
    }
}
```

Then use `ksort` to sort by key:

```
ksort($results);
```

Every item of `$results` now holds an array of filenames that are modified at the same time.

Comment: Watch out, `ksort()` like basically all array sorting functions returns true or false and acts directly on the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DirectoryIterator ( http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php ) to easy iterate over the files in a directory and get the properties of each (including last modified time).

You could simply instantiate the iterator, iterate through it and sort the items into an array of your choosing.